# Single shadow for multiple objects in Swift?

Tags: swift, join, path, shadow, uibezierpath

I want to draw a dialog bubble so I need 2 objects:

- arrow (can be drawn with `UIBezierPath` only)
- rounded rect (can be drawn with `UIBezierPath` or `UIView`+corner radius)

Example of code generated by paintcode:

```
//// Rectangle Drawing
let rectanglePath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 68, y: 38, width: 101, height: 38), cornerRadius: 5)
UIColor.gray.setFill()
rectanglePath.fill()


//// Polygon Drawing
let polygonPath = UIBezierPath()
polygonPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 118, y: 25.5))
polygonPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 125.36, y: 38.25))
polygonPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 110.64, y: 38.25))
polygonPath.close()
UIColor.gray.setFill()
polygonPath.fill()
```

The problem is if I add shadow to this code then it is applied twice and may overlap the objects.

I could replace 2 objects with one but the complexity of code is increased significantly (drawing rect and 3 points will be replaced with ~50 points including "control points").

So is it possible to join `rectanglePath` and `polygonPath` to draw single shadow somehow without this complexity?

Comment: How about you `append` one path to the other and then apply the shadow to the single path?

Comment: @Sweeper The question is about how to do that?

Comment: There is a method called [`append`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath/1624377-append)...

Comment: Or are you having trouble adding the shadow once, rather than creating a single path? If so, can you show how you are adding the shadow right now? A [mcve] is needed.

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks I figured it didn't work because I add the shadow separately and it involves superview. But the view is not added to parent view so mask is drawn but not the shadow